# AWS SNS - How to subscribe an endpoint to a topic using 'application' as protocol?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto

boto.sns
sns_connection.subscribe(topic, protocol , endpoint)

unable to subscribe an endpoint to a topic using 'application' as protocol.
Current choices - for are:
email|email-json|http|https|sqs|sms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc strings are out of date in boto.  I have submitted a pull request (https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/2017) to fix that.  However, you can still specify a value of `application` for the `protocol` parameter.  Boto is not trying to validate that parameter value.  Make sure you supply the appropriate value for the `endpoint` parameter.